# what does grunt "test command" do on npm init

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, gruntjs

I'm trying to learn grunt. When I run npm init, I get a prompt in the process of creating a package.json file that asks for "test command" - I'm not sure how to utilize this, or what it's expecting. It doesn't seem to be well documented. If I leave it blank, I get this in the resulting package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    //"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Can anybody shed some light on how to set up a test script?

Comment: Well, are you unit testing your application?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

at first, the scripts-property in your package.json has nothing to do with grunt itself. its just a cli-command from npm, wich will be run if you run

```
$ npm test
```

read more about that here: https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html

e.g. if you test your application with the [grunt & nodeunit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-nodeunit) you could just add that to the scripts-block

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "grunt nodeunit"
}
```

and your nodeunit-task is run if you run 'npm test'

this basically makes it easier for continuous integration and so on, if you change your underlying testframework.

of course you could add an [alias-task](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task) if you need more to be done before and after your tests are run (e.g. concatenation before, cleanup after)

Comment: In extension to this you can do package.json with mutiple commands in npm test, like if you wanna grunt and compile your sass you could just do - "test": "grunt && compass compile"

Comment: @SimonPertersen: i would not do it like this. there is a grunt-compass plugin out there. if you want to run tests and afterwards compile compass, you should use this plugin, register an alias task which runs this chain, and let npm test run your alias task!

Comment: It was just an example you could do tons of commands or use it for other stuff it was just because i had this on my hand - but alias tasks is only for the grunt, can i run terminal commands aswell?

Comment: of course you can, but for almost everything you want to do there, will be a grunt plugin available. if not, write one for the task you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer above you can run your test command when you specify it during creation of package json from cmd or by editing the json file manually.
Basically as per the npm docs it is used to run the provided package's test script.

[npm docs test](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/test)

In my case , Iam using it to test an angular application using Jasmine(spec.js files) a sample usage can be found in this article :-

[Getting Started with Node.js and Jasmine](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-js-and-jasmine)